# Raising A manually defined error with a class

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

```
class MissingnumError (CheckError):
    def __init__(self, num, type =  "Animal" ):
        self.num = num
        self.type = type 
    def __str__(self):
        forma = '%s #%d not found'%(self.type,self.num) 
        return forma
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self)
```

If I want to access this Error and raise it from a different class, how do I do it??
Say I am defining some function inside a different class, I will be for looping over a list of animals but if the animal is not found I will need to raise the above error. How do I access it and get it to print the **str** : forma???

example:

```
def myfnction(self, animal):
    for something in listofthings:
        if something == animal:
            return something
    raise MissingnumError
```

How do I raise this Error correctly, through accessing the class above and printing the **str**???

Comment: The error requires some error number. Suppose its 10, then do `raise MissingnumError(10)`.

Comment: What is a `CheckError` that you are inheriting from? Is it a subclass of `Exception`? You can check this way: `issubclass(CheckError, Exception)`.

Comment: `raise MissingnumError(1)` or whatever `num` should be. (By the way, if `num` is missing, `MissingnumError` probably should *not* have a `num` attribute; or the exception name is a misnomer.)

Comment: That's not really a valid error, as you cannot raise it directly from the class (`MissingnumError()` fails, so `raise MissingnumError` will too). Also the temporary assignment to `forma` is pointless and rather than implement `__str__` then get `__repr__` to call it, you can *just implement `__repr__`*.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html

Answer (score 0):

You just `raise` it, supplying an instance to `raise` with the appropriate required argument (`num` as defined in your `__init__`):

```
raise MissingnumError(1)
```

If no handler is specified Python will simply `__repr__` it and return the message as specified:

```
MissingnumError: Animal #1 not found
```

Two additional notes:

- Don't use `type` as an argument name. `type` is already used by Python for another purpose and you mask it inside the method body.
- `CheckError` should inherit from `Exception`, this is required by any object you supply to `raise`.

Comment: What do you mean required argument??

Comment: @RickTeachey no it won't, my point was that `raise MissingnumError` would be a problem.

Comment: @Wanderer they mean the argument to `__init__ ` that's required, `num`.

Comment: How should I raise it then. TRY - EXCEPT ??

Comment: @Wanderer you raise the error using `raise MissingnumError(<some number>)` exactly as shown in this answer. Try it.

Comment: @Wanderer that depends, do you need to handle it or not? If you do, you raise it inside a `try-except` where `except` catches `MissingnumError`. If you don't just `raise` it.

Comment: SO no need for Try-except to raise it??

Comment: Handling  might be helpful. Just for my personal knowledge. thanks

Comment: Whether you need to handle it is up to you. Would handle it just like any other exception: `except MissingnumError:` etc etc.